# How to read the value of file path or how to iterate over its values

Tags: java, json

JSON

```
 {
    "category": "value",
    "file_path": [
        "file1",
        "file2"
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
String Str =  jsonObject.getString("file_path");
```

How do I get these two values?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's completely unclear to me what you're asking. Perhaps you could try phrasing it differently? Thanks.

Comment: `JSONOBject jb = new JSONOBject("mystring");
JSONArray jr = jb.getJSONArray("file_path");
String value1 = jr.get(0);
String value1 = jr.get(1);`